# How to find first tr with ID that does not have a matching attribute via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying to solve this but no luck so far. I have the following HTML...

```html
<table id="datatable">
  <tbody id="datarows">
    <tr id="row1" class="datarow" style="display: table-row;">...</tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr id="row2" class="datarow" style="display: table-row;">...</tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr id="row3" class="datarow" style="display: table-row;">...</tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr id="row4" class="datarow">...</tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr id="row5" class="datarow">...</tr> 
    <tr></tr>
    <tr id="row6" class="datarow">...</tr> 
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Why does my JavaScript want to target row1, when it's supposed to target row4?  Or perhaps there is an intuitive to say, add the style attribute only to the next `#row<number>` that doesn't have it...? am I close?

```js
    window.jQuery("#datatable #datarows tr[id^='row']:not([style='display: table-row']:first)").css({"display":"table-row"});
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're using jQuery to apply styles? Why not just add `display: table-row` to `.datarow` and keep it all in CSS? Of course, that leads to the question, what is setting `tr` to have something other than `display: table-row` (its default value) that you need to push it via jQuery and/or inline styles?

Comment: Good question, and under good practices you are exactly right.  It just so happens that i am working with third-party  application that is generating its own HTML and CSS. But! I do have some space to override what is happening on the page with custom JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:first` should after `not()` paranthesis not after the `attribute` brackets

```js
const element = window.jQuery("#datatable #datarows tr[id^='row']:not([style*='display: table-row']):first")

console.log(element)

element.css({"display":"table-row"});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="datatable">
  <tbody id="datarows">
    <tr id="row1" class="datarow" style="display: table-row;">...</tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr id="row2" class="datarow" style="display: table-row;">...</tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr id="row3" class="datarow" style="display: table-row;">...</tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr id="row4" class="datarow">...</tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr id="row5" class="datarow">...</tr> 
    <tr></tr>
    <tr id="row6" class="datarow">...</tr> 
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You are welcome, but it target `row4`, please run snippet and check the console.

Comment: That would be a typo. We close typo questions, as they are not going to help anyone other than the OP.

Comment: This helped me out tremendously. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work:

```
$("#datatable #datarows tr[id^='row']:not([style])").first().css("display", "table-row");
```

It should get match all the tr's with "row" in the id within the tbody "datarows" of the table "datatable" that have no style attribute.  It will filter those tr's for the first one and apply your "display: table-row" style.